# Perl + POO and Mysql error

Tags: mysql, perl

I just learned poo and i got to play with perl, achieved this but I do not get the expected output, problem with mysql? Or bad code?. other thing, the same query runs on console and workbench, and this module add chmod +x module.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
package MysqlTest;

sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $query={};
    bless($query, $class);
}
sub conexion{
    my $self=shift;
    my($database, $host, $user, $pwd)=@_;
    my $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database:$host", $user, $pwd) or die $DBI::errstr;;
    $self->{"host"}="$host";
    $self->{"database"}="$database";
    $self->{"user"}="$user";
    $self->{"pass"}="$pwd";
    my $mysqlopen = 1;
return;
}
sub consulta{
    my $self=shift;
    if (!$mysqlopen) { &conexion; }
    my $id = "SELECT * FROM save_bookmarks WHERE id='123'";
    $result = $connect->prepare($id);
    $result->execute();
    my @resultado = $result->fetchrow_array();
    print "@resultado\n";
    return;
}
sub datos{
    my $self=shift;
    print "::DATOS DE ACCESO::\n";
    while (($key, $value)=each(%$self)){
        print "$key => $value\n";
    }
}
1;
```

this file called method and created object. add to chmod  +x file.pl , but i don't know, whats not work?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use MysqlTest;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $mysqltest = MysqlTest->new();
$mysqltest->conexion("bookmarks", "localhost", "root", "pass");
$mysqltest->consulta();
```

output in console

```
DBI connect(':','',...) failed: Access denied for user 'delkav'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at MysqlTest.pm line 17.
Access denied for user 'delkav'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at MysqlTest.pm line 17.
```

any idea?

Comment: In the log message the user is 'delkav', but in the code it's 'root' - why is that?

Comment: and change passwd in mysql ... but now new error in code!

Comment: Exact duplicate with accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656212/perl-module-inherente-dbi-cant-call-method-prepare-error

Comment: @opmeitle, please do not double post

Comment: Topics are similar to speak of different themes, apart from i wanted to delete it so that it is not 'duplicate' but he won't let me!

Answer (score 3):

The OO itself is correct.

The error message comes from MySQL, denying access for the user 'delkav', but I the user you want to connect with is 'root'.

Anyway, seems your DBI->connect() line is wrong. To follow the [DBD::mysql docs](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.022/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#Class_Methods), you must change your line:

```
my $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database:$host", $user, $pwd) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

to

```
my $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;", $user, $pwd) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: solve it but changing the mysql root pass, now the problem is at line 31 -> Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at MysqlTest.pm line 31. ->  our $result = $connect->prepare($id); ??? and for you code before lines..

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $database in concatenation (.) or string at MysqlTest.pm line 18.
Use of uninitialized value $hostname in concatenation (.) or string at MysqlTest.pm line 18.
Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at MysqlTest.pm line 28.