# Perl module, inhereting from DBI , "Can't call method 'prepare'" error

Tags: perl, perl-module, dbi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perl + POO and “Can't call method ”prepare"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650738/perl-poo-and-cant-call-method-prepare)

I learned poo and i got to play with perl, create this module but when I call the segudno method I skip the following error 'Use of uninitialized value $database in concatenation ( .) ... ' Followed by 'Can't call method 'prepare' mm i don't really understand, any suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

package MysqlTest;

sub new{
    my $class = shift;
    my $query={};
    bless($query, $class);
}
sub conexion{
    my $self=shift;
    my($database, $hostname, $user, $pwd)=@_;
    $self->{"host"}=$hostname;
    $self->{"database"}=$database;
    $self->{"user"}=$user;
    $self->{"pass"}=$pwd;
    our $connect = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;", $user, $pwd) or die $DBI::errstr;
    my $mysqlopen = 1;
return;
}
sub consulta{
    my $self=shift;
    if (!my $mysqlopen) { &conexion(); }
    my $id = "SELECT * FROM save_bookmarks WHERE id='123'";
    our $result = my $connect->prepare($id);
    $result->execute();
    my @resultado = $result->fetchrow_array();
    print "@resultado\n";
    return;
}
sub datos{
    my $self=shift;
    print "::DATOS DE ACCESO::\n";
    while ((my $key, my $value)=each(%$self)){
        print "$key => $value\n";
    }
}
1;
```

in other file for call msg and created objected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MysqlTest;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $mysqltest = MysqlTest->new();
$mysqltest->conexion("bookmarks", "localhost", "root", "pass");
$mysqltest->consulta();
```

this output in console.

```
Use of uninitialized value $database in concatenation (.) or string at MysqlTest.pm line 23.
Use of uninitialized value $hostname in concatenation (.) or string at MysqlTest.pm line 23.
Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at MysqlTest.pm line 31.
```

any idea?

thanks.

Comment: como es la programacion orientada a objecto!! no hice referencia a implementarla en perl, sino la estructura de objectos, atributos, metodos, etc! ok?

Comment: Topics are similar to speak of different themes, apart from i wanted to delete it so that it is not 'duplicate' but he won't let me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code includes this line:

```
if (!my $mysqlopen) { &conexion(); }
```

You call your `conexion` sub with no arguments. However, this sub expects several arguments, including a blessed object, that you don't provide. You might want to fix that. `$database` and `$hostname` also are expected in the arguments.

Your call to `conexion` will *always* be executed, because `my $var` creates a new variable and initializes it with `undef`—and the negation of `undef` is a true value.

Then you have this statement:

```
our $result = my $connect->prepare($id);
```

`my` creates a new variable `$connect` on which you try to call the method `prepare`. This doesn't work, as the created variable is no blessed reference but simply `undef`.

#### Scope in Perl

Here is a verbose example on how lexical scope with `my` works in Perl

```
# $var doesn't exist

sub foo {
   # $var doesn't exist
   my $var;
   # $var exists
   bar();
   # $var exists
}

# $var doesn't exist

sub bar {
   # $var doesn't exist
   return;
}

# $var doesn't exist
```

You define a `my` variable `mysqlopen` in `conexion`, then redefine it in `consulta`. It is, however, not the same variable, as these variables reside in different scope.

Instead, you are likely to add fields `mysqlopen` and `connect` in the object you are passing around, as this is object data. You can then use this information just like the `host` or `database` fields.

Also, do not call the method `conexion` without an object. Objects are usually created with `new`.

---

#### Edit

It is quite difficult for me to debug your code *and* parse your English at the same time, so here is your code with the worst bugs removed. However, I have no experience with DBI, so it may not work directly:

```
sub conexion{
   my $self=shift;
   die "I need args!" unless @_;
   my($database, $hostname, $user, $pwd)=@_;
   $self->{host}     = $hostname;
   $self->{database} = $database;
   $self->{user}     = $user;
   $self->{pass}     = $pwd;
   $self->{connect}  = DBI->connect(
      "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;",
       $user,
       $pwd,
   ) or die $DBI::errstr;
   $self->{mysqlopen}= 1;
   return;
}

sub consulta{
   my $self = shift;
   if (not $self->{mysqlopen}) {
      die "This object wants to be conexioned before you consulta anything";
      # you could also do
      #    $self->conexion(DEFAULT_VALUES);
      # but then you would really *have* to provide defaults!
   }
   my $id = "SELECT * FROM save_bookmarks WHERE id='123'";
   my $result = $self->{connect}->prepare($id);
   $result->execute();
   my @resultado = $result->fetchrow_array();
   print "@resultado\n";
   return;
}
```

Comment: I understand! but not is how to modify it, If delete if (!my $mysqlopen) { &conexion(); }, my $mysqlopen =1; return and output this error Can't call method "prepare" on an undefined value at MysqlTest.pm line 30.

Comment: @opmeitle I added some info on the scoping issues you are having.

Comment: Change the code already, delete what you don't need but do not quite understand the use of bless $connect to then use it in consultation and his ves in $connect- >prepare,

Comment: @opmeitle I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand what you just said, so I just fixed the bugs in your code (and wrote it in my own style) and dumped the critical parts in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I understood perfectly, the code is poorly written thanks! For your time and explanation.

Comment: ufff !! so thanks very much!! it's perfect the code, my open mind! gracias amigo